# R equivalent of python star unpacking?

Tags: r

I have a routine in R that takes a variable number of arguments, and I need to call this routine passing an unpacked list. In python I would do

```
lst = [1,2,3]
my_func(*lst)
```

What is the equivalent syntax in R?

To be more specific, I am using shiny and I am trying to create a dynamic list of entries

This is the code.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  applist <- c(
      a(href="#", class="list-group-item", 
        h4(class="list-group-item-heading", "Entry 1"),
        p(class="list-group-item-text", "Description")
      ),
      a(href="#", class="list-group-item", 
        h4(class="list-group-item-heading", "Entry 2"),
        p(class="list-group-item-text", "Description")
      ))
   
  output$applist = renderUI(
    div(class="list-group", ... applist)
  )
}
```

Comment: You can use 3 dots `...` and pass any number of arguments, but there is no dictionary for `**` in R.  It would be the same way

Comment: Is this `div(class="list-group", ... applist)` where you are using or I thought you had a function.  If it is the parameters to a function, may be you need `do.call("functionname", arguments_to_function_in_a_list)`

Comment: Yes. The function div() is already a triple dot function, and I need to pass multiple arguments to it. However, these arguments are part of a list (applist). I need to unpack them. Passing the list won't work.

Comment: You can use `do.call(fun, list_of_args)` (base R). Or try [this](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#tidy-dots) (tidyverse).

Comment: I didn't post as an answer because with `l` as `l <- list(x = 1, y = 2, z = 3)`, this works `f <- function(x, y, z){
  x + y + z
};

do.call(f, l)` but this doesn't `f <- function(...){
  x + y + z
};

do.call(f, l)` and I think the latter is what this question is about. Not sure if there's a way to modify to make that work. You could modify the function by adding a `inputs <- list(...)` as the first line of the definition and then using `inputs$x` etc instead, but maybe there's an easier way?

Comment: @akrun ok, do I understand correctly that "list" in R is not a "list" in python?

Comment: @StefanoBorini Here, you have provided a `vector` i.e. `c(...)`.  For a `list`, it is `list(...)`, but you can convert a vector to lits with `as.list(c(...))`

Comment: @StefanoBorini. It would be better if you also post the `ui` part to make this reproducible for others to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posted by OP.

Here is how I solved. using `do.call` does the trick, but you have to be aware that lists in python is not the same as lists in R. A list in R is more similar to a mix of a dictionary and a list.

```
  applist <- list(
      class="list-group",
      a(href="#", class="list-group-item"),
      a(href="#", class="list-group-item")
  )

  output$applist = renderUI(do.call(div, applist))
```

Note how the applist contains both a named entry `class` and non-named entries. As I said, hybrid. The `do.call` then does the "unpacking", but the content of applist is then distributed as named or non-named argument. It works differently from python, where named and non-named are always separated.